# Optimization of some Python code

Tags: python, string, optimization

Working on the following problem:

> Given integers L and t, a string p of length k forms an (L,t)-clump inside a (larger) string s if there is a length L interval of s in which p appears at least t times. Appearances of p are allowed to overlap in the interval.

I came up with the following solution:

```
from collections import Counter

def clumpFinding(s, k, L, t):
    c = Counter()
    res = set()
    for e in range(k, len(s)+1):
        b = e-L-1
        if b > -1:
            c[s[b:b+k]] -= 1
        tmp = s[e-k:e]
        c[tmp] += 1
        if c[tmp] >= t:
            res.add(tmp)
    return res
```

short explanation: say `S = "0123456789", L=4, t = 3, c = {}, k = 2`

at the start we would add "01", "12", "23" to the counter after that
we remove the oldest element before adding a new one:

```
c:{01} | "123456789" -> c{01,12} | "23456789" -> ... 
-> "01" | c{12,23,34} | "456789" ->  "012" | c{23,34,45} | "56789"
```

each time a string is added to the counter we check if the count is greater or equal to t if so we add it to the result set

I would like to make this code run faster, but i'm unsure about what parts i should/can optimize.

Comment: This is when you pull out your profiler to find the slowest sections.

Comment: You should really try: https://codereview.stackoverflow.com